# Why doesn't my hash function output a dynamic value?

Tags: python, hash, sha, sha512

I'm a newbie in this field and am trying to learn a bit about how to write cryptographic hash functions.

To get some hands-on, I tried updating the [PySHA2](https://github.com/thomdixon/pysha2) algorithm for Python 3.6 and up (the original version doesn't work on Python 2.5+ and the author says he won't fix this). I don't intend to use this algorithm for any work, just coding this for the sake of knowledge.

I've reached this far:

```
import copy
import struct

_initial_hashes = [0x6a09e667f3bcc908, 0xbb67ae8584caa73b, 0x3c6ef372fe94f82b, 0xa54ff53a5f1d36f1,
                   0x510e527fade682d1, 0x9b05688c2b3e6c1f, 0x1f83d9abfb41bd6b, 0x5be0cd19137e2179]
_round_constants = [0x428a2f98d728ae22, 0x7137449123ef65cd, 0xb5c0fbcfec4d3b2f, 0xe9b5dba58189dbbc,
                    0x3956c25bf348b538, 0x59f111f1b605d019, 0x923f82a4af194f9b, 0xab1c5ed5da6d8118,
                    0xd807aa98a3030242, 0x12835b0145706fbe, 0x243185be4ee4b28c, 0x550c7dc3d5ffb4e2,
                    0x72be5d74f27b896f, 0x80deb1fe3b1696b1, 0x9bdc06a725c71235, 0xc19bf174cf692694,
                    0xe49b69c19ef14ad2, 0xefbe4786384f25e3, 0x0fc19dc68b8cd5b5, 0x240ca1cc77ac9c65,
                    0x2de92c6f592b0275, 0x4a7484aa6ea6e483, 0x5cb0a9dcbd41fbd4, 0x76f988da831153b5,
                    0x983e5152ee66dfab, 0xa831c66d2db43210, 0xb00327c898fb213f, 0xbf597fc7beef0ee4,
                    0xc6e00bf33da88fc2, 0xd5a79147930aa725, 0x06ca6351e003826f, 0x142929670a0e6e70,
                    0x27b70a8546d22ffc, 0x2e1b21385c26c926, 0x4d2c6dfc5ac42aed, 0x53380d139d95b3df,
                    0x650a73548baf63de, 0x766a0abb3c77b2a8, 0x81c2c92e47edaee6, 0x92722c851482353b,
                    0xa2bfe8a14cf10364, 0xa81a664bbc423001, 0xc24b8b70d0f89791, 0xc76c51a30654be30,
                    0xd192e819d6ef5218, 0xd69906245565a910, 0xf40e35855771202a, 0x106aa07032bbd1b8,
                    0x19a4c116b8d2d0c8, 0x1e376c085141ab53, 0x2748774cdf8eeb99, 0x34b0bcb5e19b48a8,
                    0x391c0cb3c5c95a63, 0x4ed8aa4ae3418acb, 0x5b9cca4f7763e373, 0x682e6ff3d6b2b8a3,
                    0x748f82ee5defb2fc, 0x78a5636f43172f60, 0x84c87814a1f0ab72, 0x8cc702081a6439ec,
                    0x90befffa23631e28, 0xa4506cebde82bde9, 0xbef9a3f7b2c67915, 0xc67178f2e372532b,
                    0xca273eceea26619c, 0xd186b8c721c0c207, 0xeada7dd6cde0eb1e, 0xf57d4f7fee6ed178,
                    0x06f067aa72176fba, 0x0a637dc5a2c898a6, 0x113f9804bef90dae, 0x1b710b35131c471b,
                    0x28db77f523047d84, 0x32caab7b40c72493, 0x3c9ebe0a15c9bebc, 0x431d67c49c100d4c,
                    0x4cc5d4becb3e42b6, 0x597f299cfc657e2a, 0x5fcb6fab3ad6faec, 0x6c44198c4a475817]


def _rit_rot(on: int, by: int) -> int:
    """
    helper function for right rotation as it isn't done by a simple bitwise operation (xor is done by '^')
    :param on: value to be rotated
    :param by: value by which to rotate
    :return: right rotated 'on'
    """
    return ((on >> by) | (on << (64 - by))) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF


def hash_main(chunk):
    global _initial_hashes, _round_constants
    # start the hashing process
    # to begin, create a place to store the 80 words that we'll make
    words = [0] * 80

    # first 16 words will be saved without any changes
    words[:16] = struct.unpack('!16Q', chunk)

    # extend these 16 words into the remaining 64 words of 'message schedule array'
    for i in range(16, 80):
        part_1 = _rit_rot(words[i - 15], 1) ^ _rit_rot(words[i - 15], 8) ^ (words[i - 15] >> 7)
        part_2 = _rit_rot(words[i - 2], 19) ^ _rit_rot(words[i - 2], 61) ^ (words[i - 2] >> 6)
        words[i] = (words[i - 16] + part_1 + words[i - 7] + part_2) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

        # create the working variables
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = _initial_hashes

        # start the compression function
        for z in range(80):
            var_1 = _rit_rot(a, 28) ^ _rit_rot(a, 34) ^ _rit_rot(a, 39)
            var_2 = _rit_rot(e, 14) ^ _rit_rot(e, 18) ^ _rit_rot(e, 41)
            var_3 = (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c)
            var_4 = (e & f) ^ ((~e) & g)
            temp_1 = var_1 + var_3
            temp_2 = h + var_2 + var_4 + _round_constants[z] + words[z]

            # remix the hashes
            h = g
            g = f
            f = e
            e = (d + temp_2) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            d = c
            c = b
            b = a
            a = (temp_1 + temp_2) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

            # add this chunk to initial hashes
            _initial_hashes = [(x + y) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for x, y in zip(_initial_hashes,
                                                                            [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h])]


def _sha_backend_update(text_copy, _buffer, _counter):
    """
    backend function that hashes given string
    """
    global _initial_hashes, _round_constants
    # create variables for cycling
    _buffer += text_copy
    _counter += len(text_copy)

    # assert the variables are correct
    if not text_copy:
        return
    if type(text_copy) is not str:
        raise TypeError("Invalid Object! Please enter a valid string for hashing!")

    # break the buffer into 128-bit chunks
    while len(_buffer) >= 128:
        chunk = _buffer[:128].encode()[1:]
        hash_main(chunk)
        _buffer = _buffer[128:]


def sha_backend_digest(text_to_hash: str, _buffer: str, _counter: int,
                       _output_size: int, hex_output: bool = False):
    # initialize variables
    variable_x = _counter & 0x7F
    length = str(struct.pack('!Q', _counter << 3))

    # set the thresholds
    if variable_x < 112:
        padding_len = 111 - variable_x
    else:
        padding_len = 239 - variable_x

    # make a copy of the text_to_hash before starting hashing
    text_copy = copy.deepcopy(text_to_hash)
    m = '\x80' + ('\x00' * (padding_len + 8)) + length

    # run the update function
    _sha_backend_update(text_copy, _buffer, _counter)

    # return the hash value
    return_val = [hex(stuff) for stuff in _initial_hashes[:_output_size]]

    if hex_output is True:
        return_val = [int(stuff, base=16) for stuff in return_val]
        return return_val

    return ''.join(return_val)


def sha_512(text_to_hash: str, hex_digest: bool = False) -> str:
    """
    frontend function for SHA512 hashing
    :return: hashed string
    """
    # before anything, check if the input is correct
    if not text_to_hash:
        return ""
    if type(text_to_hash) is not str:
        raise TypeError("Invalid content! Please provide content in correct format for hashing!")

    # initialize default variables
    _buffer = ''
    _counter = 0
    _output_size = 8

    # start the backend function
    return sha_backend_digest(text_to_hash, _buffer, _counter, _output_size, hex_output=hex_digest)


message = "This is a string to be hashed"
from hashlib import sha512
print("hashlib gives: ", sha512(message.encode()).hexdigest())
print("I give: ", sha_512(message))
```

As is obvious, I don't understand a lot of things in this algorithm and have literally copied many parts from the original code (also, I know it isn't good practice to write everything in a single function but I find it easier when trying to understand something).

But the biggest problem I have right now is **it doesn't work!** Whatever input message I provide to my function, it gives the same output:

```
0x6a09e667f3bcc9080xbb67ae8584caa73b0x3c6ef372fe94f82b0xa54ff53a5f1d36f1
0x510e527fade682d10x9b05688c2b3e6c1f0x1f83d9abfb41bd6b0x5be0cd19137e2179
```

I wrote a code at the bottom to compare it with python's `hashlib` module.

Where am I going wrong in this and how do I fix this?

***EDIT:*** As mentioned in the comments, I tried to feed in a longer `message` string and the code seems to be working (it still gives longer output than `hashlib` though):

```
message = "This is a string to be hashed. I'll try to make this string as long as possible by adding" \
          "as much information to it as I can, in the hopes that this string would somehow become longer than" \
          "128 bits and my code can run properly. Hopefully, this is already longer than 128 bits, so lets see" \
          "how it works..."

hash: 0x6fcc0f346f2577800x334bd9b6c1178a970x90964a3f45f7b5bb0xc14033d12f6607e60xb598bea0a8b0ac1e0x116b0e134691ab540x73d88e77e5b862ba0x89181da7462c5574

message = "This is a string to be hashed. I'll try to make this string as long as possible by adding" \
          "as much information to it as I can, in the hopes that this string would somehow become longer than"

hash: 0x166e40ab03bc98750xe81fe34168b6994f0xe56b81bd5972b5560x8789265c3a56b30b0x2c810d652ea7b1550xa23ca2704602a8240x12ffb1ec8f3dd6d10x88c29f84cbef8988
```

Comment: I don't even know if this is the correct site for this kind of question, so if someone can suggest/migrate this to another site where I'm more likely to get answers to this, please do :D

Comment: It's indeed not the place to ask. This site is about discussing the algorithms and techniques, not implementation details/code. It seems however that you're trying to implement SHA2, and are comparing with SHA3. Make sure you're comparing your work against the correct hash function!

Comment: @RubenDeSmet ah, totally forgot about that, thanks! Any suggestions on where I should ask this to get answers?

Comment: I've migrated to SO because non-working code is definitely welcome here. My hint to you is not to compare output values but **intermediate values**, taken from a known good implementation. Yes, trying to keep everything in one function *can* be helpful (although splitting into different functions generally also shows a lot of the inner structure); however, it keeps *other people* from understanding the code. And currently, that other people are us.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for migrating! I wasn't able to check intermediate values as I can't find any other implementation other than `hashlib` (which I can't manipulate to get intermediate values). I tried working with PySHA2 but it doesn't work in Python 3 (as said by its author). Also, the original code structure is the same as PySHA2 (link in the question) so I didn't bother keeping the structure same. I can still change my code according to that if you say

Comment: The advantage of subroutines is that you can test each one in isolation.

Comment: @stark I'll update the code to segregate into different functions ASAP :)

Comment: I note some bits in your output are the same as the initial hash

Comment: It seems to me that if  `text_to_hash` is small then `text_copy` is also small, and thus the buffer is too small in `while len(_buffer) >= 128:`, so the while loop never runs. You need to make 1024 bit / 128 byte blocks for SHA-512. @stark Yes, exactly :)

Comment: I have updated my code (hopefully without breaking anything). @MaartenBodewes ...which means cutting the _buffer into 1024-bit long pieces instead of 128-bit long ones, right?

Comment: No, 128 *bytes* is fine, but you need to process at least the last padded block. Generally we don't expect the code in question to be updated significantly because it would invalidate answers that are being written.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes would copying a segment of the last block to make it 128 bytes long be fine (I mean it terms of cryptography)? Also, as you said, I tried making the string longer and it seems to work. I'll update it in the post

Comment: So generally you try and take one 128 byte block from the binary message, update the hash state using the information in that block, then move to the next one until you have a partial or 0 byte block. That block you need to pad & add size indication (in bits) and process. If you've not enough space for the padding / size indication then you need yet another block consisting entirely of padding and the size indication. If you read carefully, then you **always** process at least one block.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that's...a lot to to take in (did I mention I'm a newbie?). Can you give a resource for the padding function or how it works?

Comment: Hmm, it is already in `sha_backend_digest` (the 0x80 followed by zero bytes and the `length` which is input size * 8 (`_counter << 3`). At this point you really need to use a debugger and step through the algorithm, paying specific attention to the code right behind `# add this chunk to initial hashes`. I'd have to start up a debugger to help you best, but I don't have the time for that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ohkay, gotcha. thanks man :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it seems to be working just fine after I did what you said (it turns out I simply bypassed that `padding_len` step since I didn't understand what it was doing). If you can add that as an answer, I will be happy to select it as correct. Thanks again for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll always have to pad the message. Padding and adding the length are always required as last step of the SHA-2 process. Currently you weren't performing that last step (to completion).

Here are my last two comments that pointed you in the right direction:

> So generally you try and take one 128 byte block from the binary message, update the hash state using the information in that block, then move to the next one until you have a partial or 0 byte block. That block you need to pad & add size indication (in bits) and process. If you've not enough space for the padding / size indication then you need yet another block consisting entirely of padding and the size indication. If you read carefully, then you always process at least one block.

and

> Hmm, it is already in `sha_backend_digest` (the `0x80` followed by zero bytes and the length which is input size * 8 `(_counter << 3)`.

But of course you do need to perform that and not skip any step.